# how to implement payment methods in iphone?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have implemented product management system.I want to add one new features in which user can buy product from the iphone so user can do payment for particular products.
But i dont know how it possible.If you have any idea about that then please help me for this query.

Edit:
I have seen amazon.com and eBay application in apple store.I want to implement similar amazon.com and eBay application.For particular product buying or purchase.I have no idea how to implement.
If you have any reference documents then please provide me so it will be help full to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to sell stuff via an iPhone app. The only exception is Store Kit with its in app purchases, but you aren't allowed to sell real world stuff there. Only virtual stuff that users can consume on their phone/ipod/ipad.

Comment: You can of course sell a service. For example, as with the Spotify application.

Comment: Read what I wrote, its allowed as long as its consumable on the phone.
Source: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html
(11)

Comment: Interesting, Apple states clearly that they don't want this ("Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected")
I must admit that I never used spotify as it isn't available here in germany. I just looked at the website and saw that you can buy offline music listening. Would you mind telling me how they sell their stuff?

Comment: You pay something like £10 a month and without an account, the App does nothing but show a login screen.

Comment: It may just be that big companies can do what small time developers can't because of things like PR with Apple. It's obviously not a written rule but just what I've heard from experience of other developers at conferences.

Comment: So this isn't done in the app at all? This would be allowed from what I read, but I guess that isn't the solution JohnWhite is looking for.
But interesting anyway, thanks for clarifying this

Comment: Frankly, I think you are misreading their guideline. You are, of course, allowed to sell things via an iphone app. You are not allowed to sell "real" things using IAP, nor are you allowed to sell functionality circumventing the app store. But you can sell stuff all you want. Look at Amazon.